# 555 as a Digital Coupler

Tags: 555, opto-isolator, digital-communications

I want to read MIDI data with an arduino (specifically an ATtiny85) for use in a synthesizer. The only method I'm aware of involves using an optocoupler such as the 6N138 found on this [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Send-and-Receive-MIDI-with-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS). It seems quite practical but unfortunately I don't have one on hand right now and shipping might take too long for my project. I was wondering if it would be possible to configure a 555 timer to do the same task instead. I quickly threw together this circuit of what I'm working with.[image: 555 Digital Optoisolator]

The circuit should compare the voltage difference between the relevant MIDI pins and reproduce this difference as a logic level at the output. My setup as a whole is not working but without an oscilloscope nearby I can't confirm that this is the buggy part (the other option being the code I'm using). Is my circuit a valid alternative to an optocoupler?

EDIT: Removed "Isolator" from title.

Comment: Do you really believe that a 555 will provide any isolation?

Comment: I wonder what your definition of "isolation" is...

Comment: If you need opto isolator then you need an opto isolator.

Comment: Not _true_ isolation, no. I figured the 555 would be able to reproduce a logic value sent into it. If the input voltage representing this level spiked for whatever reason it would damage the 555 but not my microprocessor. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @PlasmaHH By "isolation" I meant something like "protected from voltage spikes". The 555 can only output a finite voltage and I was hoping this would prevent the arduino from frying in the event of a voltage spike at the input. I might still be wrong about that though...

Comment: In a MIDI input, the purpose of the optocoupler is not protection again voltage spikes but prevention of a ground loop. (In fact, the resistors and the diode are intended to protect the optocoupler against voltage spikes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you don't know/understand what *isolation* means when dealing with [optocouplers/optoisolators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator).

It doesn't mean that there is some sort of circuit buffering separating the two circuits. It really means **electrical isolation**, i.e. there is no current flowing from one part to the other (an optocoupler does that).

An optocoupler is essentially an LED and a photodiode (or a phototransistor) optically coupled in the same package. The LED and the photodiode don't share any electrical connection. They only "communicate" through the light generated by the LED. Therefore the "input section" (the LED) can be driven by a circuit which is completely isolated from the circuit connected to the "output section" (the photodiode/phototransistor).

[image]

This allows two circuits that must remain electrically isolated to communicate.

So the answer is ***no, an NE555 cannot substitute a circuit which performs electrical isolation***.

If you're desperate or don't need specific performance/reliability you could try [building a poor man's optocoupler](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-an-Optocoupler/). And [here is another attempt](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-simple-optocoupler/).

Important Note: **if your circuit needs an optocoupler for stringent safety reasons, using one of those home made one could pose some serious safety risks, so be warned!**

That is, I wouldn't trust a mains-powered heart-beat detector using a home-made optocoupler to be used on my chest!!!

Comment: Thanks for that. I sort of figured I was wrong about how I used "isolation" but I also meant it in the sense of "protection". Would my circuit by able to protect my arduino in the event of a voltage spike by sacrificing the 555?

Comment: @PatagonianRat: no

Answer (score 4):

> The circuit should compare the voltage difference between the relevant MIDI pins and reproduce this difference as a logic level at the output.

No, this circuit can't work. MIDI is a current-loop interface, not a differential voltage interface.

The two pins at the output of one MIDI device are designed to directly drive the LED in the optocoupler at the input of the next MIDI device. Usually, one pin is tied high through a resistor, and the other pin is switched between ground and open through another resistor.

If you want to detect this switching using something other than an LED, then you need to provide a path for that current, such as a load resistor of a few hundred ohms, and then monitor the differential voltage across that resistor.